# Getting count of BsonDocuments using LINQ and placing results in a new list

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, count

Ok.  I am stumped because I don't know LINQ very well, but here is the problem.  I have a list of BsonDocuments with the following structure:

```
{ "Produce" : "apple", "CompanyName" : "Ralphs", "Link" : "www.ralphs.com" },
{ "Produce" : "apple", "CompanyName" : "Ralphs", "Link" : "www.ralphs.com" },
{ "Produce" : "apple", "CompanyName" : "Albertsons", "Link" : "www.albertsons.com" },
{ "Produce" : "banana", "CompanyName" : "Ralphs", "Link" : "www.ralphs.com" }
```

How do I query this list using LINQ to find a specific count match and place it in a new list of BsonDocuments using all the data as a unique key?  For example, if I were to group the items above, I would get:

```
{ "Produce" : "apple", "CompanyName" : "Ralphs", "Link" : "www.ralphs.com" }, // Count = 2
{ "Produce" : "apple", "CompanyName" : "Albertsons", "Link" : "www.albertsons.com" }, // Count = 1
{ "Produce" : "banana", "CompanyName" : "Ralphs", "Link" : "www.ralphs.com" } // Count = 1
```

But since I only want a specific count number (e.g. 2), my final list should only contain

```
{ "Produce" : "apple", "CompanyName" : "Ralphs", "Link" : "www.ralphs.com" }, // Count = 2
```

I already know how to do this with the aggregation framework against a MongoDB database, but I'd like to know how to do this in memory with LINQ if possible.  Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    class Class1
    {
        public string Produce { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Class1> lst = new List<Class1>();
        lst.Add(new Class1() { Produce = "a", CompanyName="b", Link="c" });
        lst.Add(new Class1() { Produce = "a", CompanyName = "b", Link = "c" });
        lst.Add(new Class1() { Produce = "a", CompanyName = "d", Link = "c" });
        lst.Add(new Class1() { Produce = "e", CompanyName = "b", Link = "c" });

        var result = lst.GroupBy(x => x.Produce + x.CompanyName + x.Link).Select(g => new { Produce = g.First().Produce,
            Company = g.First().CompanyName,
            Link = g.First().Link,
            Count = g.Count()
        }).ToList();

    }
```